# I am trying to create a contract to stake ERC20 token and getting this error "ERC20: insufficient allowance". I used approveContract to approve

Tags: solidity, erc-20-approve

I first approve allowance through 'approveContract' function and then try to transfer the amount using 'transferFrom' function of ERC20. But getting error :ERC20: insufficient allowance:

```
function stake(address tAddress,uint amount) public {
        require(amount>0,"Can't be zero");
        uint balance=ERC20(tAddress).balanceOf(msg.sender);
        require(amount<=balance,"Not enough token");
        stakeAmount[msg.sender][tAddress]+=amount;
        TimeStamp[msg.sender][tAddress]=block.timestamp;
        CustomToken token = CustomToken(tAddress);
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender,address(this),amount);
        emit StakeSuccess(tAddress,amount,TimeStamp[msg.sender][tAddress]);
    }

    function approveContract(address tAddress, uint256 amount) public {
        require(isToken[tAddress], "Token not supported");
        CustomToken token = CustomToken(tAddress);
        token.approve(address(this), amount);
    }
```

Comment: A contract cannot approve itself. It is the user who should call approve with the contract address.